# what difference for ....loop syntax in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
 num = {num1 : 10 , num2 : 17, num3 : 22};
```

Case 1

```
for (let key in num){
                      alert(key);
}
```

Case 2

```
for (key in num){
                      alert(key);
}
```

> key and let key

what is diference and how we use it